# VueJS 3 - V-model not updating the initial data value

Tags: vuejs3, chromium, v-model

I read all the similar topics in here and still can't tell what's wrong...

The v-model in not making the data reactive.

I’m using vue@3.2.31 with Chromium browser version 88 on Linux and I have the following code:

> < input min=“1” id=“run-times” v-model.number=“runTimes”/>

with

> data() { return { runTimes: 1, }; },

The strange thing is that only on this browser, the v-model is not updating the initial value of runTimes.
It is not only on this part of code but on all codes where I use v-model.
On all other browsers everything is working correctly tested it with Windows, MacOS and Android.

Have anyone had any issues with the update with v-model?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sooo, nobody have came across such issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, that there is a virtual keyboard extension, which does not fire the correct events in order the reactivity to work.

I'm still trying to see a solution without reworking the code, but in the end, it could be done getting the value from the element itself when you want to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes some browsers don't support reactive v-model updating, especially mobile browsers. In this case you can use `:value="yourModelValue"`.

For example:

```html
<input type="text" :value="myValue" @input="inputData($event)">
```

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      myValue: '',
    }
  },

  methods: {
    inputData($event) {
      // Value will update reactively
      $event.target.value;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

why `v-model.number=“runTimes”`?,

It should just be`v-model=“runTimes”`

Comment: This is just to specify the format of the variable.
Already tested it with and without .number - does not work